# Apps take up space but do not show up on app list

Tags: internal-storage

I'm developing applications using Icenium (new IDE for hybrid app development), I have been testing all day without any problems, deleting the apps from phone, rebuilding the apps, etc.

At some point during the night, my apps stopped being displayed on my phone when I compile them, the apps take up space but don't actually show up anywhere on my phone.

Things I tried:

- Reboot
- App Cache Cleaner (app)
- Fast Reboot (app)

I only managed to free up a couple of MB though (right now I have 15MB out of 153MB free - even though I have very little apps installed!!).

What can I do to delete these application files and hopefully being able tor rebuild my apps again?

EDIT:
Also, when I try to move apps from SD card to phone - I get the "Not enough storage space" error, even though it should supposedly fit (app is smaller than 15MB).

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes, I have root access.

Comment: To close-voters: Though it's a dev asking this, and it's about his self-developed apps, the real question is "how to remove an app from the Android device if it's not visible in the list of installed apps" -- which IMHO is perfectly suitable according to our [FAQ]. @JoaoFerreira you might want to edit your question's title, if I assumed correctly :) For the second part of your question: please check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). If that doesn't answer this part, please ask a *new* question and point that out.

Answer (score 1):

Install Titanium Backup.  Hit menu key on device.  Under storage option click clean dalvik.  Might not free up much, but maybe a little

Answer (score 1):

As they are user-installed apps, thy should be user-uninstallable. Not being shown in the list of installed apps complicates things a little, but should not make them impossible: as you developed the apps yourself, you will for sure know their package names (I will use `com.package.name` in my example).

#### One-time setup

1. Your computer must have ADB installed. As you say you develop yourself, you most likely will have the Android SDK installed already (for other readers: Either install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/), or check [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) if you don't need the full SDK).
2. Turn on *USB Debugging* on your device (if you not already have done so, that is)
3. Connect your device to your computer
4. Your computer must be ready to deal with your device. For Windows, you will need suitable drivers (see [Universal Android USB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/)). On Linux (and most likely Mac as well) you just need to configure `udev` (see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) again).

#### Deal with the app

Above steps only need to be performed once to be able to deal with your device. Now for the remove-part:

1. Connect your device to your computer with *USB Debugging* enabled
2. From a shell/cmd window, run `adb shell pm uninstall com.package.name`

Done. You optionally can add the `-k` parameter to `pm uninstall` if you just want to uninstall the app, but keep its data.

**Edit:** As Dan pointed out in below comment, instead of using `adb shell pm uninstall`, you also could simply use `adb uninstall` (which can count as an "alias", and thus also supports the `-k` parameter). One more remark is: if you've already got some terminal app on your Android device, you could also take this instead of adb, and simply use `pm uninstall` locally.

Comment: You don't need the `shell pm` business: just `adb uninstall com.package.name` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Even if an app doesn't show up in the app drawer, it must still be listed in **Settings** → **Apps**. You can uninstall it from that screen. If it's not listed there, it really isn't installed.

Uninstalled apps get their internal storage deleted automatically, but files they created can still take up space on your SD card. Of course, it's also possible that they added content to other apps (such as contacts) which would continue to take up space.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, another great option is to use ES File Explorer. it has a great root Explorer function that let's you view all installed apps at the system level. I've used this to delete apps on an amazon firetv that do not show up in the regular list. I'm all about using the terminal, but this is another option.